# Response.sendRedirct() URL is not opening on the browser

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

**Usecase:** I have a public rest endpoint in a `SpringBoot` application which will redirect a user to an `Angular` page.

I have below code to redirect the request from my `RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // some logice

    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:4200/#/entry");
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);   
}
```

To test the endpoint I have an HTML page with below code:

```
<h1>Public Tracking</h1>
<button onclick="loadDoc()">Search</button>
<script>
    function loadDoc() {
        console.log("button clicked");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/api/search", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

From the browser console and network, I could see the redirected request being received, but the page is not opening. I could see the Angular page in the response body but, how could I get it on the browser?

[image: success response]

PS: I have seen other posts that say `response.sendRedirect()` is not working. In my case, it's working but, I'm not getting the page opened.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working with the form submission. Happened to fix with below code:

```
<form method="POST" id="mySearchForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('mySearchForm').action = "http://localhost:8080/api/search";
</script>
```